# Problems with clearTimeout

Tags: javascript, jquery, settimeout

I have the following method when one of my div is being clicked:

```
   current_money = parseInt($(this).find('.text-white').text());
   var  current_category_id = $(this).find('.category_id').val();
   game.getQuestion(current_category_id, current_money);
   game.selected_question = $(this);
    var result = 15;
    var seconds = 15;
     check = function(){
        if(seconds < 0)
        {
            checkAnswer(-1, 0, null);
        }
        else
        {

            var percentage = Math.round((seconds / result) * 100);
            $('#countDownChart').data('easyPieChart').update(percentage);
            $('#time').text(seconds);
            seconds--;

            setTimeout(check, 1700); // check again in a second
        }
    }

    check();
```

This shows a popup.

When an element in the popup is clicked it calls the following method:

```
    function checkAnswer(id, is_correct, element)
{
    clearTimeout(check);
    blink(element, is_correct)

    var new_value;
    if(is_correct)
    {
       var old_value =  $('#game_points').text();
       new_value = parseInt(old_value)+current_money;
       game.num_correct++;
    }
    else
    {
        var old_value =  $('#game_points').text();
        new_value = parseInt(old_value)-current_money;
    }
    current_money = new_value;
    game.score = current_money;

    $('#game_points').text(new_value);
    game.disableQuestion();


    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: '/Jeopardy/setAnswer',
        dataType: 'json',
        data: {
            request: 'ajax',
            answer_id: id,
            game_id: game.id,
            phase_id: game.phase_id,
            question_id: game.current_question.id,
            is_correct:is_correct
        },
        success: function (data)
        {

        }
    });
    game.questionBox.fadeOutAnimation();
    game.num_questions--;
    if(game.num_questions == 0)
    {
        game.finish();
    }
}
```

As you can see the first line i clear the timeout.

However it continues running untill seconds hits 0 and then calls the `checkAnswer` method.

Can anyone tell me why this is happening?

**Update**

Here is the top of my script:

```
    readUrlVars();
var status = true;
var current_question = null;
var questionBox;
var game = null;
var current_money;
var check;
jQuery(document).ready(function () {

    init();
    $('#game_table').on('click','.question',function()
    {
        if(status == 'true')
        {
           current_money = parseInt($(this).find('.text-white').text());
           var  current_category_id = $(this).find('.category_id').val();
           game.getQuestion(current_category_id, current_money);
           game.selected_question = $(this);
            var result = 15;
            var seconds = 15;
             check = function(){
                if(seconds < 0)
                {
                    checkAnswer(-1, 0, null);
                }
                else
                {

                    var percentage = Math.round((seconds / result) * 100);
                    $('#countDownChart').data('easyPieChart').update(percentage);
                    $('#time').text(seconds);
                    seconds--;

                    setTimeout(check, 1700); // check again in a second
                }
            }

            check();

        }
    })

    $('#option_list').on('mouseenter','.optionOutCss', function()
    {
        $(this).attr('class','optionOverCss');
    })
    $('#option_list').on('mouseleave','.optionOverCss', function()
    {
        $(this).attr('class','optionOutCss');
    })

})
```

**Update 2**

Ive updated my code to the following:

```
           timeout = setTimeout(timer, 1700);

function timer()
```

{

```
if(seconds < 0)
{
    checkAnswer(-1, 0, null);
}
else
{

    var percentage = Math.round((seconds / result) * 100);
    $('#countDownChart').data('easyPieChart').update(percentage);
    $('#time').text(seconds);
    seconds--;

    setTimeout(timer, 1700); // check again in a second
}
}


    clearTimeout(timeout);
```

however this did not change anything.

Comment: `var t = setTimeout(...` and then `clearTimeout(t)`, where `t` is in proper scope.

Comment: @abhitalks isnt that what i have right now expect that the global variable is called check?

Comment: @abhitalks note that my check variable is a global variable

Comment: `setTimeout(check, 1700)`: here `check` is the function which has to be called after 1700 ms. This should be `var t = setTimeout(check, 1700);`

Comment: @Marc Rasmussen Your `check` variable is a function whereas `clearTimeout` expects numeric id returned by `setTimeout`.

Comment: @hindmost but if it needs to be recursive how can i make it 1 unique id?

Comment: @Marc Rasmussen Just store it as global variable. Actually your function is not recursive.

Comment: `setTimeout(timer, 1700); // check again in a second` should be changed to `timeout = setTimeout(timer, 1700); // check again in a second` in your **update 2**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not clearing the timeout.

When you set the timeout use,

```
 timeout = setTimeout(check, 1700);
```

when you clear the timeout use,

```
 clearTimeout(timeout);
```

See the  [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers.setTimeout)

---

Also because your timeout is a constant, you can use the function `setInterval` here and get rid of the recursion,

```
current_money = parseInt($(this).find('.text-white').text());
var  current_category_id = $(this).find('.category_id').val();
game.getQuestion(current_category_id, current_money);
game.selected_question = $(this);
var result = 15;
var seconds = 15;

var check = function(){
    if(seconds < 0)
    {
        checkAnswer(-1, 0, null);
    }
    else
    {
        var percentage = Math.round((seconds / result) * 100);
        $('#countDownChart').data('easyPieChart').update(percentage);
        $('#time').text(seconds);
        seconds--;
    }
}

interval = setInterval(check, 1700);
```

Then clear it with,

```
clearInterval(interval);
```

see [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers.setInterval)

Comment: how can do this recursively since it has to be called more or less 15 times?

Comment: @MarcRasmussen - why do you think it needs to be called 15 times - `setTimeout` executes only once, you just want to clear the executing one.

Comment: Even though it's recursive the `timeout` variable keeps a reference of the last timeout event. Therefore you can clear it with `clearTimeout(timeout)`

Comment: @SampathLiyanage The above function works however it is missing the delay of 1700 mili seconds before calling the method again. how would i implement that?

Answer (score 1):

This is because of execution cycle of your code, once the function has started executing it will run until you return from that function. can you tell what functionality you are trying to achieve may be that can help in understanding and a diffrent approach can be thought of

Comment: My "program" is a quiz and the function you see is a 15 sec count down animation on screen this is why it has to be repeated untill seconds is 0

Comment: To request clarification on the question post a comment. Dont use the answers to request clarification.

Comment: in the check function...you can do one thing, check if the button clicked event is for answering question if so then use return statement and go out of function.